# Onclick function not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, onclick

Here is my View code..

While I Click the Image `onClick="q1('1'); return false"` the browser goes top not selecting the image. But it works well in Chrome and Firefox. In Safari 
it throw the error as "object input element is not a function evaluating elem(q1)"

And my Script is..

```
function q1(option)
{
    if (document.getElementById("q1").value == option)
    {

    }
    else if (document.getElementById("q1").value!= "")
    {
        a = document.getElementById("q1").value;
        document.getElementById('op'+a).className = "";

        if (option == '1')
            document.getElementById("op1").className +=  "visited";
        else if (option == '2')
            document.getElementById("op2").className +=  "visited";
        else if (option == '3')
            document.getElementById("op3").className +=  "visited";
        else if (option == '4')
            document.getElementById("op4").className +=  "visited";
        else if (option == '5')
            document.getElementById("op5").className +=  "visited";

    }
    else
    {
        if (option == '1')
            document.getElementById("op1").className +=  "visited";
        else if (option == '2')
            document.getElementById("op2").className +=  "visited";
        else if (option == '3')
            document.getElementById("op3").className +=  "visited";
        else if (option == '4')
            document.getElementById("op4").className +=  "visited";
        else if (option == '5')
            document.getElementById("op5").className +=  "visited";
    }

    document.getElementById("q1").value = option;
}
```

Comment: do you have javascript enabled in safari? have you tried this onClick="javascript:q1('1'); return false;" or onClick="javascript:q1(1); return false;"

Comment: Ya tried all this steps but i couldnt solve the problem. Any other ideas dude..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might have a naming conflict between the function and the element id.  You have an html element named q1 and a function named q1.  Try rename the function to something unique?

Not that this *should* be a problem, as proven by it working in other browsers.